# How to make outlet collection of views and change their corner rounded at once?

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, iboutletcollection

i have 10 views and want to make their corner rounded at once by making a outlet collections of views.
i dont want to do them one by one there must be a shortcut to do that
help me with the code

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `forEach(_:)` on the **IBOutet Collection** and change each `view's` `cornerRadius` like so,

```
views.forEach({ $0.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0 })
```

Set the value of `cornerRadius` as per your requirement.